# 'Undefined reference' problem while using curl in dev c++

Tags: curl, libcurl, dev-c++, .a

I am trying to use curl library in Dev c++. But whenever I run the code, errors in the picture are occurring. Do you have a solution to that problem?

Here is the compiler message:

[image]

Comment: Do not link to other resources/images, show the messages here and show the code you used that caused the errors!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 1):

Instance of your program is still running. Windows does not allow to change the files in use and cannot write the new .exe on the top of the running one.

1. Stopping/killing your exe in "Task Manager"
2. if you cannot find it in Task Manager restart your computer.